# Problem to show the data returned with the for

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the for in js as follows to generate the chart with the highcharts:

```
$.getJSON('./menluvas?colt2' + '&colt2=' + colt2, function (data) {
    
    var series = [],
    len = data.length,
    i = 0;
    
 for(i;i<len;i++){
    series.push({
        name: 'Janeiro',
        data:[data[i][7], data[i][3]]
    });
  }

    $('#container2').highcharts({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container2',
            type: 'column',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 0,
            beta: 0,
            depth: 20,
        }
        },
        title: {
            text: '' +idf+  ' - AVALIAÇÃO CONSUMOS LUVAS' 
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Unidade - (1 Caixa = 100 Luvas)'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            
        }
    },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,  
                }
            }
        },
        series: series
    });

});
```

The problem is that in the series, inside the variable date, I have two values: date [i] [7] and date [i] [3], but it only returns the value of data [i] [7]. The value of data [i] [3] returns zero

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid that I don't understand where the problem is. `The value of data [i] [3] returns zero` - it seems that it is output from your database, so what else should be returned instead? Could you reproduce your case with the sample of data and describe what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Sebastian Wędzel In the database it returns this `0: data: (2) [10000, "Vinil s/ pó"] name: "Janeiro"`. 
The `data[i][3]` should return `Vinil s/ pó` and not zero.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue on some online editor?