# Separate an array with an integer and a string

Tags: javascript

I have the following array, which returns the values ​​as follows:

> ```js
> 0: data: (2) [10000, "Vinil s/ pó"] name: "Janeiro"
> ```

I'm trying to split this way:

```
var series1 = series.split(",");

var series2 = series1[1] + "," + series1[2];
```

But it gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: series.split is not a function

Code to generate the array

```
var series = [],
    len = data.length,
    i = 0;
    
 for(i;i<len;i++){
    series.push({
        name: 'Janeiro',
        data:[data[i][7], data[i][3]]
    });
}
```

Link to draw the graph [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934800/problem-to-show-the-data-returned-with-the-for)

Comment: If it's actually an array, there's no need to work at the string level. What you'e quoted as what you have isn't at all clear. Is it one big string? Is it an object with properties where one of the properties is an array? Something else?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I agree, that's normally what I do as well (suggesting the language-specific SE site). But, since in this case it was just a single line, I believe that was just an OP's inattention, they probably understand English.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder  I added the code that generates the array to try to explain my problem better. This problem arose when trying to solve the problem I posed in this : [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934800/problem-to-show-the-data-returned-with-the-for)

Comment: Bruno, please show us what result you want.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Yes, it was inattention of my pie. I apologize

Comment: `series[0].data[0]==10000`, `series[0].data[1]=="Vinil s/ pó"`.

Comment: @iAmOren The result I want: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgIs9.png) Where I mark in red, which appears zero, the value of the variable data [i] [3], which is inside the array series, should appear

Comment: `Vinil s/ pó`?
`series[0].data[1]`.

Comment: @iAmOren Yes, that's it. How you put here `series [0] .date [0] == 10000, series [0] .data [1] == "Vinil S/Pó"` returns. The problem is how to put it that way on the chart, in the series.

Comment: That's how the `series` Array was generated.
I don't know how you draw the chart - can you show the code for that in the question (use `Edit` + add the link you gave)?

Comment: @iAmOren I already added the link to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to split anything, your data is *already* in separate entries in the array, at `series[index].data[0]` (the number) and `series[index].data[1]` (the string). So you can access those in a loop, for instance:

```
// (`i` is already declared in the OP's code)
for (i = 0; i < series.length; ++i) {
    var num = series[i].data[0];
    var str = series[i].data[1];
    console.log(num, str);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var data = [
    [,,,"Vinil s/ pó",,,,10000],
    [,,,"Another value",,,,20000],
];
var series = [],
    len = data.length,
    i = 0;
    
 for(i;i<len;i++){
    series.push({
        name: 'Janeiro',
        data:[data[i][7], data[i][3]]
    });
}

// Using each entry:
for (i = 0; i < series.length; ++i) {
    var num = series[i].data[0];
    var str = series[i].data[1];
    console.log(num, str);
}
```

Or with ES2015+ language features (`for-of`, destructuring, and `const`):

```
// Using each entry
for (const {data: [num, str]} of series) {
    console.log(num, str);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var data = [
    [,,,"Vinil s/ pó",,,,10000],
    [,,,"Another value",,,,20000],
];
var series = [],
    len = data.length,
    i = 0;
    
 for(i;i<len;i++){
    series.push({
        name: 'Janeiro',
        data:[data[i][7], data[i][3]]
    });
}

// Using each entry
for (const {data: [num, str]} of series) {
    console.log(num, str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Series seems to be an array of objects, since split is a String method you cant use it on arrays nor objects.

Inside each object you have the key data which points to an array so you don't have to split it in the way you seem to be trying.

Just access series[index].data[innerArrIndex]